# Warning "Message template is not a compile time constant"

Tags: c#

Within a class I have to following code which occurs several times:

```csharp
var message = $"My Message with Value1='{value1}' and Value2='{value2}'.";
Log.Error(exception, message);
throw new CustomException(message);
```

`message` is always different, but the approach of logging the error and throwing an exception is always the same.

Now both Rider and ReSharper within Visual Studio give the following warning: `Message template is not a compile time constant`.

I can refactor it into this and the warning goes away:

```csharp
const string messagePattern = "My Message with Value1='{0}' and Value2='{1}'.";
var messageParameters = new object[] { value1, value2 };
Log.Error(exception, messagePattern, messageParameters);
throw new CustomException(string.Format(messagePattern, messageParameters));
```

But how can I make this code reusable to avoid that I have to repeat the logging and throwing? This is what I'd like to do:

```csharp
const string messagePattern = "My Message with Value1='{0}' and Value2='{1}'.";
var messageParameters = new object[] { value1, value2 };
LogAndThrow(exception, messagePattern, messageParameters);

void LogAndThrow(Exception exception, string messagePattern, string messageParameters)
{
    Log.Error(exception, messagePattern, messageParameters);
    throw new CustomException(string.Format(messagePattern, messageParameters));
}
```

But this gives the same error because `messagePattern` is not a `const` anymore and declaring it as `in string messagePattern` doesn't help.

Is there any way to make this code reusable except disabling the warning?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, your code will throw an exception if the value of `value1` is (for example) `"{0}"`. Basically your first piece of code is is *not* considering what it passes in to be a format string with placeholders, but an *already formatted* string. You shouldn't call `string.Format` with that.

I would suggest you provide overloads for `LogAndThrow` and `CustomException` that have a single string parameter (for the already-formatted message) and no additional `messageParameters` parameter (because you don't need it), which does *not* call `string.Format`.

Comment: But with that the warning `Message template is not a compile time constant.` remains

Comment: @mu88: Without seeing the new code, ideally in the form of an [mcve], it's hard to know how to advise further. Basically you need to make it clear to ReSharper/Rider that the string is really *not* intended to be a format string.

Answer (score -3):

To get rid of the warning `message` should be `"My Message with ..."` without the `$`.

---

Your comments confused me and I came up with the following snippet that contains your desired code. I'm not reviewing your method here, I am addressing the issue of the incorrect use of `$`.

The result is `My Message with Value1='1' and Value2='A'.` and not warning (or error if this was .net 5) about `message` not being a constant.

```
// BTW. Changed 'string' to 'object[]'
static void LogAndThrow(Exception exception, string messagePattern, object[] messageParameters)
{
    //Log.Error(exception, messagePattern, messageParameters);

    throw new Exception(string.Format(messagePattern, messageParameters));
}

static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        const string messagePattern = "My Message with Value1='{0}' and Value2='{1}'."; // No $
        var messageParameters = new object[] { 1, "A" };
        LogAndThrow(new Exception("X"), messagePattern, messageParameters);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, but how does that answer to the core of my question?

Comment: I'm confused. This removes the warning.

Comment: Didn't YOU make it reusable already? The question contains `This is what I'd like to do:` section and this answer just makes it work.

Comment: No I didn't - I would like to have it reusable and without the warning `Message template is not a compile time constant`, but my code doesn't work